# Actionscript 3 Visual Studio 2010 plugin - setting the classpath in sapphire steel's Amethyst

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, actionscript-3, ide, flex4

I have just installed the latest version of the sapphire steel Amethyst plug in for visual studio 2010.  I want to use an external library - Away3D to be specific.  In FlashDevelop I'd go to project --> properties --> classpath --> add classpath and enter the appropriate url.

I'm not all that familiar with Visual Studio.  Can someone please describe for me the equivalent operation with this visual studio plugin?

Thank you!
Marc

Answer (score 0):

I added the library in the form of a .swc file to the project references under the solution.  Right click --> add....  Visual studio is an easy place to get lost in...